# Undefined function '' for input arguments of type 'char'

Tags: matlab, ode

I'm learning how to solve systems of ODEs in matlab, but somehow I can't get the examples to work.
I'm trying to follow the section "Represent Numeric Approximations as Functions" at
http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ug/solve-equations-numerically.html#math-solving-equations-numerically-diff-equations

but when I enter Line 1

```
IVP := {y''(t) = t*y'(t), y(0) = 0, y'(0) = 1/3}:
```

it throws the error

```
Undefined function 'IVP' for input arguments of type 'char'.
```

any idea what's going on here? Do i need some extra libraries or something?
I'm pretty new to matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is `MuPAD` syntax.  You need to have `MuPAD` notebook if you want to do that in MATLAB.  To see if you have it, in MATLAB, at the top, go to your `APPS` tab, then select `MuPAD Notebook` to start a new notebook, like so:

[image]

Once you select the `MuPad Notebook` option, then go ahead and follow that tutorial that you linked us to.  Here's a reference to start a new Notebook for more details.  http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/create-mupad-notebooks-and-program-files.html

This is what I get when I run your `IVP` example.  I type in the command, push <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then type in `IVP` and push <kbd>Enter</kbd> to echo the output.

[image]

As you can see, the syntax works there.  If you want to get started on `MuPAD`, it is a different syntax compared to MATLAB all together, so you should start here for some basic fundamentals: http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad-language-fundamentals.html

Good luck!